# Align element on another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm having a bit of trouble aligning the 'x' circle to the top right of the image because its grandparent has overflow: hidden style applied to it. The circle gets cut off and isn't placed in the corner of the image.

I've already spent hours searching for a right solution but just gave up.

I want to achieve this sort of result.

[image]

Here's plunker of what I've been trying to do.

```js
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($uibModal){
  var vm = this;

  vm.existingImages = [
    { img: 1, src: 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/c5d1ac7b9669b3bbb20ebb8444cb702a/tumblr_nxrgstujWX1sfie3io1_1280.jpg'},
    { img: 2, src: 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/13284/production/_89586487_istock_000063166549_medium.jpg'  },
    { img: 3, src: 'https://picturecorrect-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/creativity-photographer.jpg'},
{ img: 4, src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507290439931-a861b5a38200?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80'},
    { img: 5, src: 'https://www.thenorthernecho.co.uk/resources/images/8861689/?type=responsive-gallery-fullscreen'},
    { img: 6, src: 'https://oddstuffmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/forest-in-Norway-650x908.jpg'},
  ];
})
```

```css
.existing-img-gallery {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.existing-img-thumbnail {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 18%;
 padding-bottom: 18%;
 margin: 0.83%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.existing-img-container {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.existing-img-container img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

i.ion-ios-close-circle.delete-img {
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 17px;
    left: 95%;
    top: 43%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div ng-repeat="img in vm.existingImages" class="existing-img-gallery">
            <div class="existing-img-thumbnail">
               <div class="existing-img-container">
                  <i class="ion-ios-close-circle delete-img clickable"></i>
                  <img class="clickable" ng-src="{{this.img.src}}" alt="...">
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my try. Just move the element that have the `overflow:hidden`

```js
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($uibModal){
  var vm = this;

  vm.existingImages = [
    { img: 1, src: 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/c5d1ac7b9669b3bbb20ebb8444cb702a/tumblr_nxrgstujWX1sfie3io1_1280.jpg'},
    { img: 2, src: 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/13284/production/_89586487_istock_000063166549_medium.jpg'  },
    { img: 3, src: 'https://picturecorrect-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/creativity-photographer.jpg'},
{ img: 4, src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507290439931-a861b5a38200?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80'},
    { img: 5, src: 'https://www.thenorthernecho.co.uk/resources/images/8861689/?type=responsive-gallery-fullscreen'},
    { img: 6, src: 'https://oddstuffmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/forest-in-Norway-650x908.jpg'},
  ];
})
```

```css
.existing-img-gallery {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.existing-img-thumbnail {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 18%;
 padding-bottom: 18%;
 margin: 0.83%;
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.existing-img-container {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.existing-img-container img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

i.ion-ios-close-circle.delete-img {
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 17px;
    left: 95%;
    top: 43%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div ng-repeat="img in vm.existingImages" class="existing-img-gallery">
            <div class="existing-img-thumbnail">
               <i class="ion-ios-close-circle delete-img clickable"></i>
               <div class="existing-img-container">

                  <img class="clickable" ng-src="{{this.img.src}}" alt="...">
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to place the icon outside your overflow hidden container.

```js
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($uibModal){
  var vm = this;

  vm.existingImages = [
    { img: 1, src: 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/c5d1ac7b9669b3bbb20ebb8444cb702a/tumblr_nxrgstujWX1sfie3io1_1280.jpg'},
    { img: 2, src: 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/13284/production/_89586487_istock_000063166549_medium.jpg'  },
    { img: 3, src: 'https://picturecorrect-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/creativity-photographer.jpg'},
{ img: 4, src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507290439931-a861b5a38200?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80'},
    { img: 5, src: 'https://www.thenorthernecho.co.uk/resources/images/8861689/?type=responsive-gallery-fullscreen'},
    { img: 6, src: 'https://oddstuffmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/forest-in-Norway-650x908.jpg'},
  ];
})
```

```css
.existing-img-gallery {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.existing-img-thumbnail {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 18%;
 padding-bottom: 18%;
 margin: 0.83%;
}

.existing-img-container {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.existing-img-container img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

i.ion-ios-close-circle.delete-img {
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 17px;
    left: 95%;
    top: 43%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div ng-repeat="img in vm.existingImages" class="existing-img-gallery">
            <div class="existing-img-thumbnail">
               <i class="ion-ios-close-circle delete-img clickable"></i> 
               <div class="existing-img-container">
                
                    <img class="clickable" ng-src="{{this.img.src}}" alt="...">
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my answer completely. I reviewed your structure and the repeating structure is repeating the wrong element in my opinion.

I am no expert on angular, but with the part: `<div ng-repeat="img in vm.existingImages" class="existing-img-gallery">` you're basically repeating your image gallery container 6 times and the styles aren't exactly designed for such a structure.

What you could do is the following:

```
<div class="existing-img-gallery">
    <div ng-repeat="img in vm.existingImages" class="existing-img-thumbnail">
        <div class="existing-img-container">
            <img class="clickable" ng-src="{{this.img.src}}" alt="...">
        </div>
        <i class="ion-ios-close-circle delete-img clickable"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you have only one `.existing-img-gallery` and you have 6 `.existing-img-thumbnail` elements inside it. Then you just remove the `overflow: hidden` rule for `.existing-img-thumbnail`.

I think that would be an improvement on structure and you'll have more control on the styles.

Comment: This does not make the x not being 'cut off'.

Comment: I edited the code and added another div container between existing-img-thumbnail and existing-img-gallery.

Comment: I edited my answer completely and modified the structure idea you have. Does it work that way?

Answer (score -1):

So if you cannot get away from the `overflow: hidden` as the other answers assume, which means you cannot make room for it outside, there is no other way but to do it *inside* each tile.

Key differences in this snippet:

- The icon is really the only item that needs some kind of absolute positioning here as it is the only thing that needs to be moved from its natural position.
- The space inside each tile so the icon can be rendered on the corner without cropping is created with padding in the `existing-img-container`.
- The `existing-img-container` doesn't need an absolute position, this will only make things more complex for you in the future.
- You don't need to translate the icon with a transform as it's already absolute positioned.
- Nothing fancy needs to be done to the actual `img` tag, just enforcing the width so that it doesn't try to overflow the tile.
- You might want to play a bit with the alignment inside the flexbox to distribute them exactly like what you had in mind.

PS: Provided the entire snippet for completeness, but the changes are only in the css rules.

```js
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($uibModal){
  var vm = this;

  vm.existingImages = [
    { img: 1, src: 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/c5d1ac7b9669b3bbb20ebb8444cb702a/tumblr_nxrgstujWX1sfie3io1_1280.jpg'},
    { img: 2, src: 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/13284/production/_89586487_istock_000063166549_medium.jpg'  },
    { img: 3, src: 'https://picturecorrect-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/creativity-photographer.jpg'},
{ img: 4, src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507290439931-a861b5a38200?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80'},
    { img: 5, src: 'https://www.thenorthernecho.co.uk/resources/images/8861689/?type=responsive-gallery-fullscreen'},
    { img: 6, src: 'https://oddstuffmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/forest-in-Norway-650x908.jpg'},
  ];
})
```

```css
.existing-img-gallery {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.existing-img-thumbnail {
    float: left;
    width: 18%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.existing-img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.existing-img-container img {
    width: 100%;
}

i.ion-ios-close-circle.delete-img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 17px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div ng-repeat="img in vm.existingImages" class="existing-img-gallery">
            <div class="existing-img-thumbnail">
               <div class="existing-img-container">
                  <i class="ion-ios-close-circle delete-img clickable"></i>
                  <img class="clickable" ng-src="{{this.img.src}}" alt="...">
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk I think you might have slightly misjudged the intention here. I did not imply that the other approaches were inherently incorrect, but rather point out that they're based on the assumption that the OP has control over the existing structure, which is often not the case, if not for the OP, surely for other people that will reach this question at some point. I'm merely providing an answer that doesn't require that control. How that would equate to that downvote is really beyond me. Cheers.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk I'm realising just now that you're the OP. You were provided with a working solution (and the one with the best alignment at that) that merely addresses a concern that's not entirely clear in the question and required some kind of effort nevertheless, and that translated to your downvote. I wish you luck progressing with your career.

Comment: The reason for the downvote was that the desired outcome isn't exactly what your answer is all about. I'd take it as a workaround but it totally changes the layout of the page. I understand it works but not exactly the way it's been described in the thread. I appreciate your time put into the question though, please don't take my downvote as something bad, it's to indicate that it kind of drifts away from mine and potentially other viewers' desired effect.

Comment: Nope it doesn't, specially if you bring up "potential other viewers" that do need that concern addressed. The solution delivers the alignment the question asks. And I'm not sure what you mean by "changes the layout of the page" as the structure being kept the same is precisely what this solution delivers. If you had other kinds of requirements you did not mention in the question (which you still did not clarify as to how it doesn't work the way it's been described), then I don't think the problem is with the answer, or that it should equate to a downvote for not meeting those requirements.

Comment: Well, consider "I want to achieve this sort of result. (image)" being significant part of the question. Thanks for the input anyway.